# Reshuffling a column by group many times and put the results in new columns

Tags: r, random, data.table, shuffle, group

I have the following hypothetical data:

```
district <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)                                       
village <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)                              
status <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
datei <- data.table(district, village, status)
```

I want to reshuffle status based on district and put the results in new columns. I know how to do it once using the following codes:

```
datei[, randomstat := sample(status), district]
```

Now, I want to reshuffle status 1000 times and put the results in new columns. I tried the following codes:

```
n <- 1000
datei[, paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := replicate(n, list(sample(status), district))]
```

but failed. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To improve the quality of the post, can you elaborate on why it "failed"? was it an error? if so, include the error in your post. was the output not as expected ? if so then include in the post as well.

Comment: This should be done without adding 1000 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo in your code: `district` is put inside `list`, i.e., `list(sample(status), district))`, which is not correct.

---

You have the follow options:

- Enable `simplify = FALSE` when using `replicate`, e.g.,

```
datei[, paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := replicate(n, sample(status), simplify = FALSE), district]
```

- Or, wrap `sample(status)` with `list()`

```
datei[, paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := replicate(n, list(sample(status))), district]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could create your own shuffle function, here is an example for 10 columns:

```
n <- 10

reshuffle <- function(status, district) {
  unlist(mapply(function(s, d) sample(s), 
                split(status, district), 
                split(district, district), 
                SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}

datei[, (paste0("randomstat", 1:n)) := lapply(1:n, \(i) shuffle(status, district))]

datei
```

```
   district village status randomstat1 randomstat2 randomstat3 randomstat4 randomstat5 randomstat6 randomstat7 randomstat8 randomstat9 randomstat10
 1:        1       1      1           1           1           1           1           1           0           1           1           1            1
 2:        1       2      0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0            0
 3:        1       3      1           1           0           0           1           1           1           0           0           0            1
 4:        1       4      0           0           1           1           0           0           1           1           1           1            0
 5:        2       1      1           1           1           1           0           0           1           1           1           1            1
 6:        2       2      1           0           0           1           0           1           0           0           1           0            0
 7:        2       3      1           1           1           0           1           1           0           1           1           1            1
 8:        2       4      0           0           1           0           1           1           1           1           0           1            0
 9:        2       5      0           1           0           1           1           0           1           0           0           0            1
10:        3       1      1           0           0           0           1           1           0           1           1           1            1
11:        3       2      1           1           0           0           1           1           1           1           0           1            1
12:        3       3      1           0           0           0           0           1           1           1           1           1            0
13:        3       4      1           1           1           1           0           0           1           1           0           0            0
14:        3       5      0           0           1           1           1           0           0           0           1           0            1
15:        3       6      0           1           1           1           0           1           1           0           1           1            1
16:        3       7      0           1           1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

A few vectorized options using the `Rfast` package if performance is a concern:

```
library(Rfast)

n <- 1e3

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  replicate = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := replicate(n, sample(status), FALSE), district],
  reshuffle = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := lapply(1:n, \(i) reshuffle(status, district))],
  colShuffle = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(colShuffle(matrix(rep(status, n), .N, n))), district],
  colRanks = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(matrix(status[colRanks(matrix(runif(.N*n), .N, n))], .N, n)), district],
  colRanksAll = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(matrix(status[colRanks(matrix(runif(.N*n), .N, n) + match(district, unique(district)))], .N, n))],
  setup = {dt <- copy(datei)}
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#>    replicate  15.1496  17.55985  21.687518  20.56755  24.95855  37.4373   100
#>    reshuffle 120.1781 135.82605 153.436604 146.41200 160.21505 242.8556   100
#>   colShuffle   4.5537   4.94215   6.118132   5.11265   5.82665  19.3036   100
#>     colRanks   5.7100   6.08095   7.730242   6.40530   8.20650  19.7137   100
#>  colRanksAll   5.0109   5.35780   7.171746   5.59560   8.67885  17.7488   100
```

Timing a larger dataset:

```
set.seed(2037213561)

datei <- data.table(district = rep(1:1e3, sample(10, 1e3, 1)))[
  ,`:=`(village = rowid(district), status = runif(.N)%/%0.5)
]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  replicate = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := replicate(n, sample(status), FALSE), district],
  reshuffle = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := lapply(1:n, \(i) reshuffle(status, district))],
  colShuffle = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(colShuffle(matrix(rep(status, n), .N, n))), district],
  colRanks = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(matrix(status[colRanks(matrix(runif(.N*n), .N, n))], .N, n)), district],
  colRanksAll = dt[,paste0("randomstat", 1:n) := as.data.frame(matrix(status[colRanks(matrix(runif(.N*n), .N, n) + match(district, unique(district)))], .N, n))],
  setup = {dt <- copy(datei)},
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr       min        lq      mean     median         uq        max neval
#>    replicate 5602.0342 6649.0791 7237.3350  7318.1749  7641.8868  8434.8158    10
#>    reshuffle 7348.9950 8237.6315 9946.4001 10728.3559 11320.5539 11680.5648    10
#>   colShuffle 1521.4851 1578.3194 2024.9663  2181.7678  2312.6861  2368.4342    10
#>     colRanks 2063.0544 2633.7768 2784.5394  2868.1073  3097.8065  3232.0499    10
#>  colRanksAll  374.6916  403.4064  467.1745   478.0322   521.1787   580.5176    10
```